# Two orthogonal cameras : stereo calibration?

Tags: ros, stereo-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use the stereo camera calibrator `camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py` to calibrate two cameras orthogonal each other? Imagine orthogonal coordinate system xyz. Camera 1 is viewing origin from (1,0,0) and camera 2 is viewing origin from (0,1,0).

The point is, that a colleague thinks that the cameras must look nearly into the same direction.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11025/two-orthogonal-cameras-:-stereo-calibration?/) by [Daniel Eberli](https://answers.ros.org/users/940/daniel-eberli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2011-08-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think based on the theory, stereo cameras work based on the idea that both of the cameras will have some common features in their frames.

That's not to say that you couldn't implement some sort of time-based (parallax?) stereo system, using common features across frames through multiple time-steps and across the camera frames.  I'm not sure how much work has been done on that, though.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0